# AWS S3 bucket tagging

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tags

I know how to place tags on S3 object, for example(based on AWS Java SDK):

```
PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, new File(filePath));
List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
tags.add(new Tag("Tag 1", "This is tag 1"));
tags.add(new Tag("Tag 2", "This is tag 2"));
putRequest.setTagging(new ObjectTagging(tags));
PutObjectResult putResult = s3Client.putObject(putRequest);
```

but I need to associate some meta information with AWS S3 Bucket, so I wondering if I can place tags to AWS S3 Bucket itself? For example I need to keep client Id for each AWS S3 Bucket and then read it in AWS Lamda triggered by S3 event. Is it possible to use AWS S3 Bucket tags for this purpose and if so, please show an example. if no - please suggest a way I can achive it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following snippet to retrieve bucket tags:

```
    final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
    BucketTaggingConfiguration bucketTaggingConfiguration = s3.getBucketTaggingConfiguration("dev-udp-data");
    System.out.println(bucketTaggingConfiguration.getTagSet());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use following snippets to give tags to the bucket :

if you are creating a new bucket :

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket_tagging = s3_resource.BucketTagging("bucket_name")
    response = bucket_tagging.put(
        Tagging = {
            'TagSet' : tag_set    //your json format tag_set
    })
```

if the bucket already exists then first get the tags and append your new tags :

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket_tagging = s3.BucketTagging("bucket_name")
tags = bucket_tagging.tag_set
tags.append({'Key': 'bucket_key', 'Value': owner})
Set_Tag = bucket_tagging.put(Tagging={'TagSet':tags})
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

If don't already have a client:

```
static final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
        .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider("<your-profile-name>"))
        .build();
```

Then you have to get the tag list, if it exists, and append the new tags or create a new tagging configuration.

```
BucketTaggingConfiguration bucketTaggingConfiguration = amazonS3.getBucketTaggingConfiguration(resourceId);
if (null != bucketTaggingConfiguration) {
    bucketTaggingConfiguration.getAllTagSets().get(0).setTag("tagKey", "tagValue");
}
else {
    TagSet tagSet = new TagSet();
    tagSet.setTag("tagKey", "tagValue");

    List<TagSet> tagSetList = new ArrayList<>();
    tagSetList.add(tagSet);

    bucketTaggingConfiguration = new BucketTaggingConfiguration();
    bucketTaggingConfiguration.setTagSets(tagSetList);
}
amazonS3.setBucketTaggingConfiguration(new SetBucketTaggingConfigurationRequest(resourceId, bucketTaggingConfiguration));
```